# How could I save symbol with dash with yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

My i18n file is zh-TW,

And I have enum for my user model

```
enum :language, [:'zh-TW', :jp]
```

However, I can not save user the this value

```
# can't be  save

      user.language = :'zh-TW',
      user.save

# NameError: uninitialized constant TW
user.language= :zh-TW
```

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape indicator characters ('-'). You can achieve that by quoting value. See an example bellow:

```
user.language= :"zh-TW"
```